# How can I reuse a single thread for all timer_create callbacks when using SIGEV_THREAD?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, posix

I have a timer that runs at regular intervals. I create the timer using **timer_create()** using the SIGEV_THREAD option. This will fire a callback on a thread when the timer expires, rather than send a SIGALRM signal to the process. The problem is, every time my timer expires, a new thread is spawned. This means the program spawns potentially hundreds of threads, depending on the frequency of the timer.
What would be better is to have **one thread** that handles the callbacks. I can do this when using timer_create() with signals (by using sigaction), but not threads only.
Is there any way to not use signals, but still have the timer notify the process in a single existing thread?
Or should I even worry about this from a performance perspective (threads vs signals)?

**EDIT:**

My solution was to use **SIGEV_SIGNAL** and **pthread_sigmask()**. So, I continue to rely on signals to know when my timer expires, but I can be 100% sure only a single thread (created by me) is being used to capture the signals and execute the appropriate action.

Comment: Presumably the newly spawned thread will terminate once the callback has completed, but it still sounds like a very expensive option if the timer fires frequently.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError That's exactly what I thought. Creating and destroying a thread for each timer expiration seems like a lot of inefficient work. But as far as I can tell, that's the way the API works. There's no option from what I can see to keep the timer firing callbacks on a single thread, other than to use signals.

Comment: @Synthetix +1 because interesting question (from a quick scan of the relevant Linux code it doesn't seem possible out of the box, but maybe someone will have a clever solution) - but why the aversion to signals?

Comment: @DanielKleinstein Thanks! I'm not averse to using signals, and in fact the code runs just fine using signals, but it seems odd there's no way to accomplish the same thing using threads only. As it stands now, it seems using signals would yield higher performance. I just can't see anything good coming out of creating a new thread for each timer expiration, especially if it's running at very short intervals.

Comment: Consider redesigning your program to use `timerfd_create` instead.

Comment: Look into the `SIGEV_THREAD_ID` option if you don't mind being linux-specific. Or `SIGEV_SIGNAL` with all but one threads blocking the desired signal.

Comment: @Shawn I ended up doing the latter, using SIGEV_SIGNAL and pthread_sigmask().

Comment: You could create one app-liftime thread to handle all timers.  The thread would manage a delta queue - a list of callback structs ordered by timeout-time.  The thread waits on an 'input' producer-consumer queue for timeout request structs with a wait-timeout set to the time of the object at the head of the delta queue.   Any thread needing a timeout would send a request with its timeout interval and callback pointer and the timer thread would get it, insert it into the delta queue and resume waiting on it's input queue.  When the input queue times out, the timer thread fires the callback.

Comment: The problem with signals, as I understand it, (may be wrong), is that they are only fired when the target thread enters the kernel for some other reason, not connected with the sending of the signal.  That adds latency.  Signals experts -please correct me if I'm wrong:)

Comment: Also, the timer-thread design works fine on Windows or any OS that does not support signals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: The basic premise that `SIGEV_THREAD` doesn't work based on signals is false - signals are the underlying mechanism through which new threads are spawned. glibc has no support for reutilizing the same thread for multiple callbacks.

---

`timer_create` doesn't behave exactly the way you think - its second parameter, `struct sigevent *restrict sevp` contains the field `sigevent_notify` which has following [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sigevent.7.html):

> SIGEV_THREAD
>
> Notify the process by invoking sigev_notify_function "as
> if" it were the start function of a new thread.  (**Among the
> implementation possibilities here are that each timer notification
> could result in the creation of a new thread, or that a single thread
> is created to receive all notifications.**)  The function is invoked
> with sigev_value as its sole argument.  If sigev_notify_attributes is
> not NULL, it should point to a pthread_attr_t structure that defines
> attributes for the new thread (see pthread_attr_init(3)).

And indeed, if we look at glibc's [implementation](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/timer_create.c#L98):

```
else
      {
    /* Create the helper thread.  */
    pthread_once (&__helper_once, __start_helper_thread);

    ...

    struct sigevent sev =
      { .sigev_value.sival_ptr = newp,
        .sigev_signo = SIGTIMER,
        .sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL | SIGEV_THREAD_ID,
        ._sigev_un = { ._pad = { [0] = __helper_tid } } };

    /* Create the timer.  */
    INTERNAL_SYSCALL_DECL (err);
    int res;
    res = INTERNAL_SYSCALL (timer_create, err, 3,
                syscall_clockid, &sev, &newp->ktimerid);
```

And we can see `__start_helper_thread`'s [implementation](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/895ef79e04a953cac1493863bcae29ad85657ee1/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/timer_routines.c#L154):

```
void
attribute_hidden
__start_helper_thread (void)
{
  ...
  int res = pthread_create (&th, &attr, timer_helper_thread, NULL);
```

And follow along to `timer_helper_thread`'s [implementation](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/895ef79e04a953cac1493863bcae29ad85657ee1/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/timer_routines.c#L70):

```
static void *
timer_helper_thread (void *arg)
{
  ...

  /* Endless loop of waiting for signals.  The loop is only ended when
     the thread is canceled.  */
  while (1)
    {
      ...
      int result = SYSCALL_CANCEL (rt_sigtimedwait, &ss, &si, NULL, _NSIG / 8);

      if (result > 0)
    {
      if (si.si_code == SI_TIMER)
        {
          struct timer *tk = (struct timer *) si.si_ptr;
          ...
            (void) pthread_create (&th, &tk->attr,
                        timer_sigev_thread, td);
```

So - at least at the glibc level - when using `SIGEV_THREAD` you are **necessarily** using signals to signal a thread to create the function anyways - and it seems like your primary motivation to begin with was avoiding the use of alarm signals.

At the Linux source code level, timers seems to work on signals alone - the `posix_timer_event` in `kernel/time/posix_timers.c` function (called by `alarm_handle_timer` in `kernel/time/alarmtimer.c`) goes straight to code in `signal.c` that necessarily sends a signal. So it doesn't seem possible  to avoid signals when working with `timer_create`, and this statement from your question - "This will fire a callback on a thread when the timer expires, rather than send a SIGALRM signal to the process." - is false (though it's true that the signal doesn't have to be `SIGALRM`).

In other words - there seem to be no performance benefits to be gained from `SIGEV_THREAD` as opposed to signals. Signals will still be used to trigger the creation of threads, and you're adding the additional overhead of creating new threads.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation. That makes sense now. I will continue to rely on SIGALRM to tell me when to trigger actions when the timer expires, with my own thread as the signal handler. That way, I can be sure the signal handler thread only gets created once and runs for the duration of the program. This seems to be the most efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to not use signals, but still have
> the timer notify the process in a single existing
> thread?

There is: timerfd API (`timerfd_create()`) provides such means.

Overall, if you can use `timerfd_create()`
(portability is not your concern), then you should.
Because SIGEV_THREAD is completely broken: it can spawn
the arbitrary amount of threads if your handler is not
fast enough, and because of that you can't even use
`timer_getoverrun()` reliably.

`SIGEV_THREAD_ID` is not a solution either because,
while being non-portable, you also can't easily get
the tid for it as not many libc'es implement
`pthread_getthreadid_np()` to get tid from `pthread_t`.

So if you have to use `timer_create()` then
`SIGEV_SIGNAL` + `pthread_sigmask()` is what "kinda"
works. At least you can use `timer_getoverrun()`
there, but its still very weird: `timer_getoverrun()`
is specified to provide the amount of extra overruns
that happened between signal queuing and dequeuing.
But if you ask how about overruns that happened after
the signal dequeue but before your prog called
`timer_getoverrun()`, then you won't find any answer
unless you look into the linux sources. From there
it can be seen that linux actually measures an
overruns between subsequent signal dequeuings, so
it can be though of as adding the lost overruns to
the next signal delivery. Plus, as you already mentioned,
directing the timer signals to the particular thread
is not always reliable: some unaware lib could create
the thread and alter sigmask to use it with its own
timer, but would instead steal your timer's signals.
And so on.

Its good that linux provides the legacy-free APIs
like `timerfd_create()`, but when you want to write
the portable code, you quickly find yourself out of
working solutions.